# CodeIgniter add a discount item

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I have a cart in CodeIgniter that works well. I tried to look for a discount/coupon handling, but I can't.

This is my cart code:

```
public function addToCart($id) {

    $this->load->model('products_model');

    $products = $this->products_model->getItemDetail($id);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $insert = array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->name,
            'qty' => '1',
            'price' => $product->item_eur,
            'image' => $product->image,
            'options' => array(
                'info' => $product->cart_description,
                'qty_description' => $product->qty_description
                )
            );
        $this->cart->insert($insert);
    }

    $last = end($this->cart->contents());
    echo $last['rowid'];
}
```

I thought of making a [coupon code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon#Electronic) read from the database and insert a discount as an item in the cart:

```
public function addCoupon() {
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $res = $this->products_model->getCoupon($_POST['value']);
    if($res) {
        foreach($res as $result) {
            $coupon = array(
                'id' => $result->id,
                'name' => $result->name,
                'qty' => '1',
                'price' => $result->discount,
                'options' => array(
                    'info' => 'coupon',
                    'qty_description' => ''
                    )
                );
            $this->cart->insert($coupon);
        }
        echo '1';
    }
    else {
        $this->lang->load('products');
        echo $this->lang->line('cart_notok');
    }
}
```

Where the database schema is:

```
[name:type] (example)
id:int (1)
name: varchar ('Discount of 20€')
code: varchar ('AFD1234')
discount: decimal (-20)
```

And the model:

```
public function getCoupon($code) {

    $results = $this->db->get_where('coupons', array('code' => $code));
    return $results->result();
}
```

The item gets added to the cart, but if the `'price' => $result->discount` is set to `-20` or a percentage, it gets set as +20€ and not -20€.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would like to see your model, but it seems you are passing the discount to the "price" column? If you have a DB column named discount (decimal), shouldn't the discount value go in there?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how. I'll edit with model.

Comment: ( (100-$Discount)/100 ) * $ProductPrice = Product price after discount